# Proof Check: Alternating Series Approximation Theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

**Problem:** Let $S=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ be an alternating series where $\vert a_{n+1} \vert < \vert a_n \vert$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n=0$. Let $S_n$ be the $n$th partial sum of the series. Show that $\vert S-S_n \vert \leq \vert a_{n+1} \vert$.

**Attempt:** Assume instead that $\vert S-S_n\vert > \vert a_{n+1} \vert$. Then $\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \vert S-S_n\vert=0$, implying that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \vert a_{n+1} \vert< 0$, a contradiction.  $\blacksquare$

---

I feel like I'm missing something important because my proof is way too short. A proof check would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement $|S - S_n| > |a_{n+1}|$ does not imply $\lim |S - S_n| \neq 0$.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Doesn't that imply that the limit of S-S_n=0 since the limit of the partial sum is the sum? Then the absolute value of a_n+1 has to be less than 0? Sorry about the trouble.

Comment: The inequality $|S - S_n| > |a_{n+1}|$ is assumed to hold for a particular $n$, not all $n$. So you cannot deduce anything about $\lim_{n\to \infty} |S - S_n|$.

Comment: For example, you could have $|S - S_1| > |a_2|$, but $|S - S_m| < |a_{m+1}|$ for all $m > 1$. This would imply $\lim_{m\to \infty} |S - S_m| = 0$ by the squeeze theorem since $\lim_{m\to \infty} |a_m| = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification ^^

Comment: @Mirero no problem!